# Adding library directory to PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, importerror

On Ubuntu 15.10, I am running PyCharm Community Edition version 2016.1. I have a Python file which calls `import tensorflow`, a module which depends on the CUDA library `libcudart.so.7.5`. When I run this file, I get the following error message:

```
ImportError: libcudart.so.7.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now, the file `libcudart.so.7.5` is located on my machine at `/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64`. And in Pycharm, I have added this path to `File->Settings->Project Interpreter->Interpreter Paths`. So, I am puzzled as to why PyCharm cannot find `libcudart.so.7.5` given that the directory containing it is listed as an interpreter path.

Furthermore, if I run this file from the command line, it runs fine without the above error. In my `.bashrc` file, I have the line:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-7.5/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

So this seems to be allowing the library file to be found. But how can I get PyCharm to find the library? My understanding was that adding the path to the interpreter paths was the solution, but it seems that this may not be correct...

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

PyCharm execution environment is independent of your .bashrc.

Assuming it is the environment variable set by .bashrc which is making it work in your shell, you should try to set that environment variable in the PyCharm run configurations.

In `Run -> Edit Configurations...`, add the environment variable there:

[image]

Comment: This appears to have been similar to the solution I was searching for. It looks like the issue I was facing was that I was attempting to call the predefined Environment Variable $CUDA_HOME/lib from within PyCharms Configuration Setting dialog. When I changed to the full /usr/local/cuda/lib everything started to work.

Comment: Make sure if you click the elipsis after Environmental variables and enter the variables there that you do not have quotes around the values!  Took me a little while to realise I was doing this.  Also, there's no way to change the order that they are defined (it just goes in alphabetical order) so make sure you replace $CUDA_HOME in the PATH variable with the actual cuda home as @norman_h mentioned.

Comment: I had to add $LD_LIBRARY_PATH as well. The whole thing is quite confusing. The remote python console works out of the box if you have your CUDA envs configured in .bash_profile, but since the execution of your code does not use a shell, you must add the envs to the run config.

Comment: @jvdbogae, thanks! yes you need to add LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the env variables under edit configuration as well

Answer (score -2):

I had this same problem with a Windows 7 desktop. Pycharm just messes up installing modules. I was trying to download pygame but adding a path to command prompt wasn't working. Luckily this video helped me out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MdGoAnFP-mU&list=WL&index=2
It is pretty simple to follow and should work with any module (it would just be a little different). Hope this helps!